# read table from SQL database based on a date

Tags: r

I'm trying to read a table from an SQL database using the sqlQuery function. Specifically, I want to ceate a function with a date as input and then select the data from the SQL database which match the given date. The commands are like:

```
example=function(dateA)
{sqlQuery(channel,paste("select * from TABLE","where date=dateA"))}

example('2017-10-26')
```

Note that the format of the date on the SQL table is YYYY-MM-DD and the above command works fine when the specific date is written on the sqlQuery function. i.e. when using the command:

```
sqlQuery(channel,paste("select * from TABLE","where date='2017-10-26'"))
```

nevertheless when calling the function *example* with date as input this does not work.
Does anybody know if there is a way to overcome this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `dateA` is treated as part of the string instead of replacing the *value* of `dateA`, try instead:

```
example=function(dateA){
  sqlQuery(channel,paste0("select * from TABLE","where date=", dateA))
}

example('2017-10-26')
```

Here, `dateA` is replaced with `'2017-10-26'` when you call `example`, and `paste0` pastes `"select * from TABLE","where date="` and `'2017-10-26'` (the value of `dateA`) together to form `"select * from TABLE","where date='2017-10-26'"`